# Error while importing site - duplicate field

Tags: export, import

I have exported a subsite under site collection in production and then tried to import on same subsite in dev. But I get error message that duplicate field "guid" was found.
It does not import successfully. Can anybody help me to remove error.

My basic aim is to make dev site same as prod site which include same number of list items , workflow on list etc.

Answer (score 0):

try to create Subsite on dev using the power shell without mentioning any template.

```
New-SPWeb –url http://sharepoint/subsite -name "Subsite"  –AddToTopNav
```

Now run the import on the newly created Subsite.

```
Import-SPWeb http://sharepoint/subsite -Path "c:\export.cmp" -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

Share the result.